# Relation between power & thickness of the filament

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, power

Tell me what relationship is used to solve the question given below.

> There are three bulbs of power 60, 100 and 20; which one has thickest filament for same source?
>
> (a) 100
> (b) 20
> (c) 60
> (d) All have same thickness

Answer (score 1):

Power:

$$P=VI$$

Ohm's law:

$$V=RI$$

Resistance:

$$R=\rho \frac{L}{A} $$

These should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question whose answer is not entirely obvious. There are many choices of filament dimension which can satisfy the power equations, some of them with bigger diamters and some of them with smaller diamters. However, the real constraint is that all filaments must operate at the same temperature. To make an effective light bulb, the tungsten filament must operate at just that temperature where it is radiating effectively in the optical region without melting.

This means a 100 watt filament must have exactly twice the *surface area* as a 50-watt filament (obviously it has half the resistance). The surface area goes as (length)*(diameter); the resistance goes as (length)/(diameter)^2.

With these constraints you can solve the problem. I will leave out the details, but if I assume a 50-watt filament with a length of 100 and a diameter of 1, I then get a 100-watt filament with a length of 133 and a diamter of 1.6 (these are approximate).

Answer (score -1):

the correct answer is (b).
This is because the electric power is directly proportional to the resistance and the resistance is inversely proportional to the diameter of the wire, so the wire with the lower diameter leads to higher power.

Comment: Thanks. In general, it is discouraged to post complete answers to homework-like questions. A hint or a conceptual answer is always preferred. This way, OP can solve the question themselves.